Trying to pass a funtionality to a composable , what is a better design?
So i have a bio-metric prompt implementation as below
class BiometricAuthentication(
    private val activity: AppCompatActivity
) {
   
 private val resultChannel = Channel<BiometricResult>()
    val promptResults = resultChannel.receiveAsFlow()

    fun showBiometricPrompt(
        title: String,
        description: String
    ) {
        val manager = BiometricManager.from(activity)
        val authenticators = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30) {
            BIOMETRIC_STRONG or DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
        } else BIOMETRIC_STRONG

        val promptInfo = PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(title)
            .setDescription(description)
            .setAllowedAuthenticators(authenticators)

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
            promptInfo.setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
        }

        when(manager.canAuthenticate(authenticators)) {
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.HardwareUnavailable)
                return
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> {
                resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.FeatureUnavailable)
                return
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> {
                resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationNotSet)
                return
            }
            else -> Unit
        }

        val prompt = BiometricPrompt(
            activity,
            object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationError(errString.toString()))
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                    super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
                    resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationSuccess)
                }

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    resultChannel.trySend(BiometricResult.AuthenticationFailed)
                }
            }
        )
        prompt.authenticate(promptInfo.build())
    }

    sealed interface BiometricResult {
        data object HardwareUnavailable: BiometricResult
        data object FeatureUnavailable: BiometricResult
        data class AuthenticationError(val error: String): BiometricResult
        data object AuthenticationFailed: BiometricResult
        data object AuthenticationSuccess: BiometricResult
        data object AuthenticationNotSet: BiometricResult
    }
}

Now to call this i implement in MainActivity as Follows
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val promptManager by lazy {
        BiometricAuthentication(this)
    }


    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            navController = rememberNavController()
            SetupNavGraph(navController = navController, promptManager = promptManager)
        }
    }
}


And in the SetupNavGraph

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    promptManager: BiometricAuthentication
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screens.Onboarding.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screens.SomePageThatDoesntneedsBiometericStuffOne.route) {
            OnBoarding(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel())
        }
        composable(route = Screens.SomePageThatDoesntneedsBiometericStuffTwo.route){
            RegisterUserPageOne(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.SomePageThatneedsBiometericStuffOne.route){
            RegisterUserPageTwo(navController = navController, biometricPromptManager = promptManager)
        }
   }
}


As you can tell by the design that i am passing a service (in future maybe more services can come as well) to few composables and to few i am not passing and in future theres going to be more composables of which few needs it and few doesnt . This design intuitively feels bad as in some i pass and some i dont pass (or correct me if i am wrong). Please tell me a better way to design this architecture.
Edit adding more details : So For instance we have BiometricAuthentication passed from MainActivity to SetupnavGraph. Once its reached there its passed on to SomePageThatneedsBiometericStuffOne and in other composables its not passed. So in SetupNavGraph we have navController and promptManager of which navcontroller is definitely passed to each composable but promptManager only to one composable . My question is such a design bad or not ?

I don't see anything wrong with your design. Can you elaborate why it feels bad?

@BartvanIngenSchenau in SetupNavGraph i pass some properties to some composables and some i dont and in futre this might grow and therefore in some coposable few services are passed and in some few aint but at the SetupNavGraph parameters all services will be present is that bad ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

added more details @Community
